# Pair runtime fault from std

Tags: c++, sum

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

main(){
    int n,m;
    set<int> number;
    int num;
    int query[m];
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> num;
        number.insert(num);
    }
    for(size_t j=0;j<m;j++){
        cin >> query[j];
    }
    for(int l=0;l<m;l++){
        for(auto k:number){
            if(number.find(query[l]-k)!=number.end()){
                cout << "YES" << endl;
                break;
            }else{
              cout << "NO" << endl;
              break;
            }
        }
    } }
```

Why my code can't run ?
When I compile and I run it, the execution says this:

[image: how it says]

How  can I run this code?

Comment: Hmmmm, somebody might wanna report this to Google, they're not doing a very good job there...

Comment: m is uninitialized. query[m] is undefined behaviour. n is uninitialized, for loop is again undefined beh

Comment: And the C++ language standard doesn't support VLA (variable-length-arrays) in any case.

Comment: You should assign values to `m` and `n` before you use them and you should use a `vector` rather than the variable length array you are using.

Comment: You need to debug your program. A debugger normally comes with your IDE. You also should enable all warnings in your compiler and treat them as errors.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,m;
    set<int> number;
    int num;
    cin >> m >> n;
    int query[m];
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> num;
        number.insert(num);
    }
    for(size_t j=0;j<m;j++){
        cin >> query[j];
    }
    for(int l=0;l<m;l++){
        for(auto k:number){
            if(number.find(query[l]-k)!=number.end()){
                cout << "YES" << endl;
                break;
            } else {
                cout << "NO" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This code allocates the array "query" with m (inserted by user) elements on the stack at run time. The new C++ compilers provide this capability to allocate the memory on the stack itself at run time for local variables.

Comment: A lot more issues in the code that need to be addressed.

Comment: The `int query[m];` will *not* compile with a properly functioning C++ compiler (unless `m` is defined as `const`, which it isn't in this case).